# can't execute gnu parallel when called from cron, but works from command line

Tags: php, permissions, cron, gnu-parallel

I have this command in cron on an Amazon EC2 ami linux (centos) instance:

```
10 9 * * * php -f /var/scripts/schtask/schtask.php
```

Inside this program, it runs this line using the exec() function calling [gnu parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel):

```
parallel -j-1 < /var/scripts/_working_files/schtask/schtask/_output/micros_schtask__2017-02-22__09.10.01__4ec2d995fd6fb5e7c866e13502714f36.txt
```

I get a return code of:

```
127
```

when this executes. I can't find this error on the gnu parallel exit status list:

```
https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#EXIT-STATUS
```

The contents of the text file looks similar to this:

```
#comment 1
#comment 2

php -f /var/scripts/micros/scripts/micros.php /store_list:"s1"
php -f /var/scripts/micros/scripts/micros.php /store_list:"s2"
php -f /var/scripts/micros/scripts/micros.php /store_list:"s3"
```

However, if I run:

```
parallel -j-1 < /var/scripts/_working_files/schtask/schtask/_output/micros_schtask__2017-02-22__09.10.01__4ec2d995fd6fb5e7c866e13502714f36.sh
```

directly on the command line, **it works**. What does that exit code mean, and why would it not run when being called from cron?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your `php` command is not found. Run `which php` and replace it.

It might look like this: `/usr/bin/php`.

```
10 9 * * * /usr/bin/php -f /var/scripts/schtask/schtask.php
```

Also do this with `parallel`.

Comment: I added the full paths and that fixed it. Thank you!!